# Return a column of values overriding page-level filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

this is my first question on stackoverflow. I am quite new to DAX and PowerBI.
I have a table 'Products'. One of the columns is called 'Designation' and it is used as a report-level filter. I have another column 'Product category'.
My intention is to have the following features to the report:

1. A user selects a single product designation;
2. A relevant product category is retrieved;
3. All other products belonging to the same product category are displayed in a table.

I am trying to have it done the following way:

Products in Category =
VAR SelectedCategory =
CALCULATE(
VALUES(
'Product'[Product category]
),
ALLSELECTED()
)

RETURN

CALCULATETABLE(
VALUES('Products'[Designation]),
FILTER('Products', 'Products'[Product Category] = SelectedCategory)
)

I am getting an error:
A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

Answer (score 0):

For this use-case, I would do the following:

1. Create a copy of the products table with all products and related categories:

```
Product Selection = 
SUMMARIZE ( 
    'Product' , 
    'Product'[Category] , 
    'Product'[Designation]
)
```

2. Set up relationships so that a selection in `Product Selection` filters the appropriate category in `Product`. Make sure the relationship is **single direction**. This relationship is many-to-many, but as long as you understand the implications here, this is fine.

[image]

3. Use `'Product Selection'[Designation]` as a page-level filter:

[image]